# What is the type of elements inside an ItemsControl?

Tags: wpf

When I use a ListBox - the elements inside are of type ListBoxItem, for ComboBox they are ComboBoxItems. What type are they for an ItemsControl? I've been digging through Blend's templates to no avail.

I wish to create a new ControlTemplate for the items inside the ItemsControl.

To clarify with code:

EDIT: Figured out the type as shown below:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="TemplateStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ContentControl}"> <!-- Here I need the correct Type in the TargetType-tag -->
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ContentControl}"> <!-- Again, I need the correct Type in a TargetType-tag -->
                    <DockPanel>
                        <TextBlock Text="Header" DockPanel.Dock="Top"/>
                        <ContentPresenter/>
                    </DockPanel>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
</UserControl.Resources>
<ItemsControl ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource TemplateStyle}"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out by trial and error. The type inside the ItemsControl is some kind of ContentControl (probably just a ContentControl). I'll update the question for others.

Answer (score 1):

It's simply a `ContentPresenter`, which implies it will be rendered with whatever `DataTemplate` is associated with the type.

If you want to take explicit control over how the items are rendered, you can just use `ItemTemplate`:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Customers}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Comment: I need to set behaviour aside from the ItemTemplate (which is variable) - so, I need control over the ControlTemplate, but I'll try and see if I can hit it with a x:TypeOf ContentPresenter.
EDIT: That doesn't work as TargetType in the Style - I'll clarify my question.

Comment: To clarify - the Item inside the ItemsControl must be something with a Template-property - ContentPresenter does not.